# How to restrict multiple login with same user for another system in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hope all good,

I am facing the problem with multiple login system in CODEIGNITER. Means I want to that if I have logged in one system then should not be logged in on another system with same user name and password.

Thanks and regards,
Abhinit

Answer (score 0):

## Restrict multiple login :

There may be many solution for that specific problem. Here is one of them.

1. Create a login_at column on your users/admin_users table.
2. When user login & session create just update the login_at column field as current dateTime.
3. When user logout or session out update the login_at column field as null.
4. When user try to login check a additional condition like login_at column is not null.

#### Common known issue :

```
If user forgot to logout and after one day later he/she try to login its not work.
```

Comment: in this case common issue one can use cron jobs to logout daily at specific time if user forgot to do so